# backbone.js view inheritance. `this` resolution in parent

Tags: javascript, inheritance, view, backbone.js

I have a case that uses view inheritance, and my code looks essentially like:

```
parentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "some event": "business"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    business: function(e){
        ...
        this.someFunc && this.someFunc();
        ...
     }
});

childView = parentView.extend({
    events: {
        ...
    },
    constructor: function(){
       this.events = _.extend( {}, parentView.prototype.events, this.events );
       parentView.prototype.initialize.apply( this );
    },
    initialize: function(){
       _.bindAll(this);
    },
    someFunc: function(){
       ...
    }
});
```

Update: Moved `this.events` extension to the constructor.

My child view has `someFunc` in it, and during some business function in the parent view, it should call that function if it exists.  If `this` is properly set to the childView, then `this.someFunc` should exist.  This, however, is not the behaviour that I am experiencing.

During the `initialize` function (in the parent), `this` is indeed set to the child view.  However, when `some event` fires, the `business` function is called with `this` set to `parentView`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried extending `this.events` in the constructor, instead of in the initialize function? If you do this in initialize, you're too late; event delegation for the `business` function has already been setup in the constructor, and will point to `parentView` (see the call to `this.delegateEvents();` in Backbone.View's constructor).

Updated with a working example:

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    name: 'ParentView',
    events: {
        "event": "business"
    },
    business: function(e){
        this.someFunc && this.someFunc();
    }
});

ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    name: 'ChildView',
    events: {
    },
    constructor: function(){
       this.events = _.extend( {}, ParentView.prototype.events, this.events );
       console.debug( this.events );
       ParentView.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    },
    someFunc: function(){
        console.debug('someFunc; this.name=%s', this.name);
    }
});

child = new ChildView();
$( child.el ).trigger('event');
// logs 'this' in 'someFunc'; the name is 'ChildView'.
```

Comment: Okay, cool.  Can you tell me the difference between parentView.prototype.initialize and parentView.constructor.initialize?

Comment: I've updated my question: the same problem exists, even using this technique.  `parentView.constructor.initialize` is undefined.

Comment: I've also tried: `parentView.prototype.constructor`, without any luck.

Comment: Updated the answer; `parentView.constructor.initialize` was a copy/paste error, I meant `parentView.prototype.constructor` of course. Works for me!

Comment: The difference is that the `constructor` is called first and actually sets up the object; normally, you wouldn't have to touch it. `constructor` then proceeds to set up the events, and at the end calls `initialize`.

Comment: I've moved your code into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9aTs/ and the trigger doesn't seem to be working, so I can't really tell if it is doing what you are describing.

Comment: I ended up getting this to work with a few minor changes. http://jsfiddle.net/idbentley/g9aTs/3/

Answer (score 2):

<del>Actually, I'dont know if this solves your case, but I usually do this: `this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);` and works like a charm.</del> My solution is completely wrong. Here's why:

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
  method: function () {
    // does somehting cool with `this`
  }
});

var Model2 = Model1.extend({
  method: function () {
    this.constructor.__super__.method.call(this);
  }
});

var Model3 = Model2.extend({
  method: function () {
    this.constructor.__super__.method.call(this);
  }
});

var tester = new Model3();

// Boom! Say hallo to my little stack-overflowing recursive __super__ call!
tester.method();
```

The call to `this.constructor.__super__` in `Model2::method` will resolve to (drum-roll) `Model2::method`.

**Always** use `ExplicitClassName.__super__.methodName.call(this, arg1, arg2 /*...*/)` or Coffee-script's `super`.

Comment: I like using __super__ instead of hardcoding parent class name

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding this line to the initialize method of the child:

```
_.bind(this.business, this)
```

Hopefully someone can point you to a better description of the underlying mechanisms than I can provide but I'll give it a shot:

What happens is that the method will use the context of the scope it was defined in unless told otherwise.  `initialize` is told to use the context of the child when you call `parentView.prototype.initialize.apply(this)` because you are passing in the childView with the `this` reference to the apply method.

You can bind the business method to the context of the child by using the underscore.js `bind` method as described above.

Comment: Right, but that's also what the `_.bindAll` function does.  By using it without any extra parameters, it should bind to all functions in the object.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.