# Automatically extend event from a base view

Tags: backbone.js

I have a base class for all views and then in each section of the app, like profiles, I also have a base class. That way shared templates and properties can be used throughout my app on many levels.

I know that if you make the event property in a Backbone view a function instead of an object literal, it will be instantiated for you, I'm not sure how to use this to my advantage, though. My question is, what's the best way to automatically extend events created in a base view.

I know one possibility where I, on view initialize, fetch the base event class and extend my current event on to it, but it seems a little hacky, and I would have to duplicate this code on every view. If you know a better way please share.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at these posts/links (possible duplicates): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257405/backbone-js-view-inheritence-this-resolution-in-parent Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968487/sub-class-a-backbone-view-sub-class-retain-events External site: http://kalimotxocoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/playing-with-backbonejs-views.html

Comment: Hi Nupal, very valid response and thanks for doing a better check then I did. The two stackoverflow links you posted had one good answer each that was different than the one provided below. I will add them both there and make this the definitive source for this specific question (the other questions are more broad). Additionally, the  kalimotxocoding.blogspot.com blog entry is just plain horrible, requires hacking backbone.js core and doesn't actually solve anything. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'events': {
        'click .parent-something': "onParentSomethingClick"
    }
}); 

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    'events': _.extend({
        'click .something': 'onSomethingClick',
    }, ParentView.prototype.events)
});
```

It's not doing nothing, but it's the simplest way I've seen so far.
I've also created a gist on another way I've been using: https://gist.github.com/1271041

Comment: The "parent" function you provided via the github link is terrific. I'm definitely replacing my currrent _super implementation with yours. Thanks!!

Comment: Don't you want to pass your objects into _.extend() the other way around? i.e. Clone then overwrite the super class's events with the new events? That way you can overwrite super functionality with child functionality, a more familiar approach to inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I extend the parent view's events in my child view:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            'click .link': 'onLinkClick'
        }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({

        events: function(){
            return _.extend({
                'click .something': 'onSomethingClick',
            }, this.constructor.__super__.events);
        }
});
```

Note: this only works as of Backbone 0.5.3. Before that version, you couldn't define events as a function.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyO. I've heard of the non-standard but ubiquitous  `__proto__` but never heard of `__super__` in JavaScript. Is this an addition by Backbone core or is this a new thing in modern browsers?

Comment: __super__ is added by Backbone core and it maps to the inherited class' prototype.

Answer (score 2):

I believe JohnnyO's answer is the best. However I came across two other ways of doing it and I'll paste them here.

It's a pity that there is no "automatic" solution that doesn't require additional hand-written code in each new view, but it is what it is.

```
 ChildView = ParentView.extend({
     name: 'ChildView',
     events: {
     },
     constructor: function(){
        this.events = _.extend( {}, ParentView.prototype.events, this.events );
        console.debug( this.events );
        ParentView.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
     },
     someFunc: function(){
         console.debug('someFunc; this.name=%s', this.name);
     } 
 });
```

By Paul - [backbone.js view inheritence. `this` resolution in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257405/backbone-js-view-inheritence-this-resolution-in-parent)

I didn't know you could provide a constructor method in your Backbone.view.extend. Good to know.

```
 var GenericView = Backbone.View.extend({

   genericEvents: { 'click .close': 'close' },

   close: function() { console.log('closing view...'); }

 });

 var ImplView = GenericView.extend({

   events: { 'click .submit': 'submit' },

   initialize: function(options) {
     // done like this so that genericEvents don't overwrite any events
     // we've defined here (in case they share the same key)
     this.events = _.extend(this.genericEvents, this.events);
     this.delegateEvents()   
   } 
});
```

By rulfzid - [Sub Class a Backbone.View Sub Class & retain events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968487/sub-class-a-backbone-view-sub-class-retain-events)

I had already envisioned (and declined) this approach but this one has the added twist of calling your base event something else so that "genericEvents don't overwrite any events" as the author says. Unless he's talking about some kind of munging of both events you're passing inside of both events object, I'm not sure what he's talking about, I'd just use **proto** or prototype to reference the parents events. But again, good to know.

Comment: You can inline `_.extend( {}, ParentView.prototype.events, { 'click':'close' } )` right inside the ChildView's definition. No need for the constructor then.